# How to open new selenium chrome driver session using cookies from previous session to bypass a websites login credentials

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I am completely new to cookies and I want to use cookies from a previous log on in order to bypass the logon. In order to do so, Using web driver I have successfully stored my cookies in a .data file. Now when I run the program again, I want my app to skip over the log in.

Storing the cookies looks like so:

```
            Set<org.openqa.selenium.Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
        File file = new File("Cookies.data");
        try{
            file.delete();
            FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter Bwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
            for(org.openqa.selenium.Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies()) {
                Bwrite.write((ck.getName()+";"+ck.getValue()+";"+ck.getDomain()+";"+ck.getPath()+";"+ck.getExpiry()+";"+ck.isSecure()));                                                                                                    
                Bwrite.newLine();   
            }
            Bwrite.close();
            fileWrite.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I am not sure how I can use this "Cookies.data" file to open the website and skip the sign on. I tried doing something like this below but I am not truly sure how to do this and am receiving errors. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
    public static void CookieWriter(){
    try{
        File file = new File("Cookies.data");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        String strline;
        BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while ((strline = Buffreader.readLine()) != null){
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strline,";");
            while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
                String name = token.nextToken();
                String value = token.nextToken();
                String domain = token.nextToken();
                String path = token.nextToken();
                Date expiry = null;

                String val;
                if(!(val=token.nextToken()).equals("null")){
                    expiry = new Date(val);
                }
                Boolean isSecure = new Boolean(token.nextToken()).booleanValue();
                Cookie ck = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure); 
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code here does not work because "Cookie ck = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure);" Does not have a valid constructor? I also tried setting the cookie using "Set<org.openqa.selenium.Cookie> cookes = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure);" and it does not work.

Comment: you can use chrome profile to reuse session

Comment: @PDHide I tried but when I do so i am receiving error saying "invalid argument: user data directory is already in use"

Comment: close all browser before running script

Answer (score 0):

your code is quite confused me but chronology for bypass the login is:

you have to login the in application and log the cookies inside the file. then after login, should get domain cookies and add those cookies from file inside your request and navigate to the home lunch page.